# Avalonia NullReferenceException when referencing UserControl elements

Tags: c#, .net-core, avaloniaui

I am brand new to Avalonia and I have a UserControl with a custom Label. Every time I try to get/set on that UserControl I get a `NullReferenceException`. This only happens on my UserControls.

#### User Control

```
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
             x:Class="Calendar.UserControls.IconButton">
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="TestLabel" Content="test" PointerEnter="OnPointerEnter"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

#### User Control Code

```
private void OnPointerEnter(object? sender, PointerEventArgs e) {
    var text = TestLabel.Content; // NullReferenceException!
}
```

Why am I getting this null exception? This seems to work fine outside of Avalonia.

I tried

- Getting/setting in the UserControl (produced the same error)
- Using `((Label) sender).Content` instead (works fine)
- Getting/setting elements from `MainWindow.axaml` (works fine)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using `Avalonia.NameGenerator` you have to use `FindControl<T>` method to [locate the control](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/guides/basics/code-behind#locating-controls)

```
private readonly Label testLabel;
...

testLabel = this.FindControl<Label>("TestLabel");
testLabel.PointerEnter += OnPointerEnter;
```